# makeTransliterable not working on custom id

Tags: angular, google-translate, transliteration

I am using Google Transliterate API in my project.

I can have 6 divs which need to be transliterable at once, I get this from API.

This works:

```
<div id="transliterateDiv" class="text-block"
             contenteditable="true" aria-placeholder="Enter your"></div>

this.control = new 
google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(this.options);

this.control.makeTransliteratable(["transliterateDiv"]);
```

This doesn't:

```
<div [id]="text['id']" class="text-block"
             contenteditable="true" aria-placeholder="Enter your"></div>

this.control = new 
google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(this.options);
let id = this.text['id'];

let ids = [id];
this.control.makeTransliteratable(ids);
```

text['id'] returns t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6

I am unable to understand why the second option should not work.

Comment: did you tried `let ids = id.split(",");` to get the ids in an array from string?

Comment: @Akhilrajtr i mean text['id'] returns one of the following te1 or te2 or te3 etc.

Comment: it would be helpful if you cold add some more details like from where `makeTransliteratable` is used and how  you are setting values to `text['id']` and how it changes.